# Deploy Camelot Apps on Mac

Tags: python, macos, deployment, desktop-application

How do I deploy an application on mac developed with camelot?

I'm following the Camelot [documentation](http://python-camelot.s3.amazonaws.com/gpl/release/pyqt/doc/advanced/deployment.html); they describe how to deploy .eggs for Windows and Linux, generated by

```
python -O setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files
```

but don't explain how to deploy on mac.

I've tried to adapt the Linux directions by entering them almost verbatim into the command line, but have not been successful yet.